# Merge two query results with common ID

Tags: sql, process

I have run SQL into different databases and got two set of queries result (actually more than two, but to keep it simple for now). 
I need to join the two query results with common ID with VB code.

**The 1st set of query result (which is an unknown prior to the query output) looks like**

```
Item ID    Property A
I1         a1
I2         a2
I3         a3
....
```

**The 2nd set of query result (which is another unknown prior to the 2nd query output) looks like**

```
Item ID    Property B    Property B Ref Order
I1         b1-1          1
I1         b1-3          3
I1         b1-2          2
I2         b2-1          1
I2         b2-2          2
I3         b3-2          2
I3         b3-1          1
....
```

**I want to merge the two query result like this with VB code**

```
Item ID    Property A    Property B-1    Property B-2    Property B-3
I1         a1            b1-1            b1-2            b1-3
I2         a2            b2-1            b2-2   
I3         a3            b3-1            b3-2   
....
```

How would I be able to do this? Much appreciated for your help.

Edit: I think there will need to be certain level of post-processing, but is it possible with VB code?

Kong

Comment: pckong check my answer, do not forget to accept It as correct answer If It helped for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PIVOT:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp1 (
    ItemID VARCHAR(10),
    PropertyA NVARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO Temp1 (ItemID, PropertyA) VALUES  ('i1', 'a1'), 
                                              ('i2', 'a2'), 
                                              ('i3', 'a3');
CREATE TABLE Temp2 (
    ItemID VARCHAR(10),
    PropertyB NVARCHAR(40),
    PropertyBorder INT
);
INSERT INTO Temp2 (ItemID, PropertyB, PropertyBorder) VALUES  ('i1', 'b1-1', 1), 
                                                              ('i1', 'b1-3', 3), 
                                                              ('i1', 'b1-2', 2),
                                                              ('i2', 'b2-1', 1), 
                                                              ('i2', 'b2-2', 2),
                                                              ('i3', 'b3-2', 2), 
                                                              ('i3', 'b3-1', 1);

SELECT  ItemID, PropertyA, 
        [1] AS [Property B-1], 
        [2] AS [Property B-2], 
        [3] AS [Property B-3]
FROM 
    (
        SELECT Temp1.ItemID, PropertyA, PropertyB, PropertyBorder
        FROM Temp2 
        JOIN Temp1 ON Temp1.ItemID = Temp2.ItemID
    ) t2

PIVOT
(
   MIN(t2.PropertyB)
   FOR PropertyBorder IN ([1], [2], [3])
) as pvt
```

OUTPUT:

```
ItemID  PropertyA   Property B-1    Property B-2    Property B-3
i1          a1          b1-1            b1-2            b1-3
i2          a2          b2-1            b2-2            NULL
i3          a3          b3-1            b3-2            NULL
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61cbb/6)**

Comment: Updated with SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. But the above won't work... Because the initial two queries result is a variable. The MS access program firstly generates two queries result (each queries result would have more than 100 items), the two queries results are linked with their common ID (ItemID). The "Property B Ref Order" is parts of the 2nd query result that would be used to re-construct the final result.